# gomail.v2 quoted-printable encoding issue on html email body

Tags: go

I'm using gomail.v2 to send html email messages. There is a problem with the encoding / decoding of the html. Here are the relevant the lines of code:

```
    m := gomail.NewMessage()

    // ... a bunch of lines removed, for clarity...

    s, err := GenerateBodyHTML(si.MsgFName, si.Hostname, &p, t)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    m.SetBody("text/html", s)

    err = d.DialAndSend(m)
```

I generate the HTML as a string and I verified that it is correct -- I can write the contents of s to a file and open that file in a browser and it all looks fine. So, for example, here are a few lines from the middle of s:

```
<body>
<a href="http://myisolabella.com/"><img src="http://ec2-54-152-108-202.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8275/iblogosm.png"></a>
<p>Hello Tom,</p>
```

But in the 3 email clients I tested, here's what the raw message body looks like:

```
<body>
<a href=3D"http://myisolabella.com/"><img src=3D"http://ec2-54-152-108-202.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8275/iblogosm.png"></a>
<p>Hello Tom,</p>
```

So the link and image tags don't work when the message renders. The equal sign is still in quoted-printable form. Here are the relevant headers received by the email client (I removed most of them for brevity, plus nothing else looked relevant):

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

What do I need to do to get the HTML decoded correctly on the mail client?

Answer (score 0):

After digging into this problem further, the data inside the mail client *should* look the way it is shown above, and the HTML does render properly. It turns out that the first link I was looking at didn't work for a completely unrelated reason.